# Update multiple rows with values from another table and where clause in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
PK | PARENT | COMMENT
---+--------+-----------
 1 |        | I AM ONE
 2 |        | I AM TWO
 3 |      1 | I AM ONE
 4 |      1 |
 5 |      2 | I AM TWO
 6 |      2 | I AM THREE
```

I want to update the `COMMENT` field of the rows where `PARENT` is not null, so that the `COMMENT` is the same as the parent. This is the expected result:

```
PK | PARENT | COMMENT
---+--------+---------
 1 |        | I AM ONE
 2 |        | I AM TWO
 3 |      1 | I AM ONE
 4 |      1 | I AM ONE
 5 |      2 | I AM TWO
 6 |      2 | I AM TWO
```

I've tried this query:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET COMMENT =
(
select table2.COMMENT
from MYTABLE as table1
join MYTABLE as table2
on (table1.PARENT = table2.PK)
where table1.PARENT is not null
)
where PK in 
(
select table1.PK
from MYTABLE as table1
left outer join MYTABLE as table2
on (table1.PARENT = table2.PK)
where table1.PARENT is not null
)
```

but this results in all the `COMMENT` fields of rows with non-null `PARENT` to be set to "I AM ONE".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To update the rows where `Parent` is not NULL, use a statement like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ...
WHERE Parent IS NOT NULL
```

To look up the parent's comment, simply use a correlated subquery (which needs to refer to the table in the UPDATE statement, otherwise it wouldn't know which row is the current row being updated):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Comment = (SELECT Comment
               FROM MyTable AS MyParent
               WHERE MyParent.PK = MyTable.Parent)
WHERE Parent IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I asked.

Comment: I know, I'm just waiting some time to see if anyone else suggests another answer I like more.